# Why $E\tilde{X}U=0$ is not testable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, least-squares, endogeneity

For linear regression model $Y=\tilde{X}'\theta_0+U$, where $\tilde{X}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ X \end{bmatrix}$, let $\hat{\theta}_{LS}$ denote LS estimator for $\theta_0$.

How to show that the hypothesis $E\tilde{X}U=0$ is not testable?

This is basicaly the hypothesis of absence of correlation between all regressors ($\tilde{X}$) and the model error ($U$). I don't know how to approach this problem. All I've found is that in Control Function method there is a test of endogeneity.

There the test $E(VU)\ne0\Leftrightarrow\rho_0\ne0$, where $V$ is a vector of reduced form residuals, and $BLP(U|V)=b_0+\rho_0'V$. So in order to check endogeneity we need to test hypothesis $H_0:\rho_0=0$, which easily tests with the help of Wald statistics.

But how to show that $E\tilde{X}U=0$ is not testable?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As a hint, check the first order conditions in OLS estimation to see how the reduced form residuals are constructed and you will see why the assumption cannot be tested in an exactly identified model.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthiasSchmidtblaicher

Ok, lets define $\hat{Q(\theta)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{j=1}{(Y_j-\tilde{X}'_j\theta)^2}$. First order conditions we need to calculate OLS estimator:

$\bigtriangledown\hat{Q}(\theta_{LS})=\mathbf{0}_{dim(\theta)+1}$

$\bigtriangledown\hat{Q}(\theta)=-\frac{2}{n}\sum^{n}_{j=1}{(Y_j-\tilde{X}'_j\theta)\tilde{X}_j}=0 \Leftrightarrow $

$  \sum^{n}_{j=1}{\tilde{X}_j Y_j}=\sum^{n}_{j=1}{\tilde{X}_j \tilde{X}'_j \hat{\theta}}$

$ \hat{\theta_{LS}}= (\sum^{n}_{j=1}{\tilde{X}_j \tilde{X}'_j })^{-1}(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{\tilde{X}_j Y_j})$

Comment: @MatthiasSchmidtblaicher From here I can't see how the reduced form residuals are constructed. I know only that they look like $V=Y-BLP(Y|X)$. Am I looking in wrong direction?

Comment: The residual $U_j$ is given by $Y_j - \tilde{X}_j'\theta$. Also, notice that we approximate the expectation by the sum across $j$ and you see that the condition holds *by construction*.